# A proper universal name for any city or town, regardless of its size

Tags: single-word-requests, geography

I'm facing a pressing issue with choosing a proper way to call a place (city, town), regardless of its size.

1) Has to describe places of any size (from pop. 5 to 5 mil.)

2) Must describe any location that is inhabited and/or has any administrative boundaries

3) Should be easy-to-understand by Americans specifically

Basically, things like "locality", "community", "municipality", "administrative unit", "metropolitan area" etc cross my mind, but I am not too sure how exactly it will be perceived - which one is more common, and which one will be the best fit for a native ear to hear to describe both NYC and a village of 2 houses (given it is on the map).

Thanks in advance for your options, which I hope will be a great many for me to choose from! :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this because questions about naming things are off-topic: ["Naming, including naming programming variables/classes"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This isn't about brainstorming a name, motto or a brand name, variable and what not. This is a valid linguistic issue non-native speakers  like me studying English face and this will be a crime against the purpose of this whole community to not give native speakers a chance to shine a light on this legitimate question? :-)

Comment: 'Settlement' is the hypernym, but it tends to sound rather bucolic. However, ELU expects those submitting questions to do and add reasonable research (a search for 'town' in a thesaurus), and reasonable analysis (why you're not happy with x, y and z), so this question _is_ off-topic.

Comment: @MaxT Then please remove the UI context from your question, and provide a sample sentence :)

Comment: I generally use "municipality", except that when creating forms, "city" is almost invariably used, even if the "city" you live in is a rural hamlet with a population of 50 (during the high season).

Comment: Another term is "conurbation". In Britain we have several conurbations, each comprised of several towns, and local authority governmental areas, but which comprise a single urban locality e.g. London metropolitan area, West Midlands, South Lancashire, West Yorkshire, Clydeside, Tyne-Tees etc.

Comment: 'Habitation' covers any area of settlement.

Answer (score 2):

To be very general, you might choose **settlement**:

> "A settlement is a place where people have come to live and have built homes."[1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/settlement)

An interesting article on *settlement* to refer to different sizes can be found on [the BBC's GCSE Bitesize](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/geography/urban_environments/settlement_characteristics_rev4.shtml). I added an image they use for clarification below (credit goes to the BBC's GCSE Bitesize):

[image: Image from the BBC's GCSE Bitesize explaining settlement hierarchies]

Example sentences:

> "The village is a **settlement** of just fifty houses."[1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/settlement)
>
> "A large Roman **settlement** has been discovered just outside the French town."[4](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/settlement)
>
> "‘In the 1730s Slovenians and Croatians established small agricultural **settlements** in Georgia.’"[5](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/settlement)
>
> "‘By the end of the nineteenth century, Cajuns had established **settlements** in the Louisiana-Texas border region.’"[5](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/settlement)
>
> "‘Libya boasts the ruins of ancient Greek outposts, Phoenician **settlements** and Berber cities.’"[5](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/settlement)
>
> "London [...] is the capital and most populous city of England and the United Kingdom. Standing on the River Thames in the south east of the island of Great Britain, London has been a **major settlement** for two millennia."[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London)

Comment: Sure, but doesn't this sound a bit awkward in a normal speech and connotate a small place? If a person sees settlement as a title for a list with both NYC and Buford in it?

Comment: @MaxT It's used for London over millennia (it was large then too, not as large as now)(see last quote), so no. If it should be used for both places with as few as 5 and as many as 10s of millions, I think this is your best option.

Comment: Note that I considered 'settlement' unsuitable to give as an 'answer' as OP's research should have turned it up. His comment above is valid, but should have been given alongside 'settlement' in his question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for clarifying, I think it best answers OP's question, therefore I added it [as an answer rather than as a comment (click for good arguments why I chose to do so)](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8171/71848). As for OP's finding it themselves, that can be hard if you are a non-native who has only come to use the language recently.

Comment: @JJJ That is precisely the reason why ELL was set up. ELU is not aimed at beginners, and answering basic and unresearched questions leads to site mediocrity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it's a fine line between welcoming new users and outright hostility. I get your point, I really do, however, I do not agree that this question is offtopic here. I also like to refer you to this [post in meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3997/71848). If you think the question is better suited on ELL, please vote to migrate it. While I don't think you mean to come across as offensive, some may see your viewpoint as hostile, elitist or pompous (but again, offtopic here, I refer you to the discussion on meta).

Comment: +1 This looks as good an answer as any for the OP's single-word request. The references, links and examples are well-chosen. The only reservation I have with the term is that *settlement* sounds like it's associated with a *new* influx of 'settlers' - in America, the 'founding fathers' had *settlements*; their remote descendants have *cities* and *towns* etc. But the usage notes in this answer go some way to addressing that.

Comment: Those whose job it is to talk about the kinds of places where people live (town planners, local officials, civil servants) use "settlement" in precisely the sense sought by the OP, but it is their jargon and has other non-technical meanings. If it is to be used for a non-technical readership then one way of dealing with the problem would be to introduce the word "...what is known technically as a 'settlement'..."